# Why is my stylesheet not linking? I have linked it correctly

Tags: html, css

I can't see a reason why it is not linked.

The html file content

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
   
    <title>site</title>
    <link href="code_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
</html>
```

the css file content

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
            background-color: aquamarine;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: need a little bit more information on the directory structure and hosting, a link has to be available as a resource for the client to use. i.e locally you can use absolute paths but on an actual server you’ll need that resource to be available - depending on what you are trying to do it can be made available in many ways but the most basic and common is to be served from a static public folder

Comment: Please share file structure

Comment: I updated with an image, was that the file structure that you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the your CSS file is in the same directory as the HTML file. If no, then link it properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `./`

```Html
    <link href="./code_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that css file is it css format or not then check your css file is in the same directory otherwise you have to mention path clearly.Also remove that "/"in end of the element.

```
    <link href="code_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```